# multiple fancybox on same page

Tags: fancybox

I'm using fancybox with ajax request to open multilpe fancybox instances on same page:
This is html code:
`<a href="/mp_tool.php?to=51" id="box_mp1" class="comment_button_fancy" title="Mp to User">User</a>`

and this is Javascript i've used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".comment_button_fancy").click(function(){

var element = $(this);
var Ide = element.attr("id");
$("#"+Ide).fancybox();


return false;});});
</script>
```

Everything could be ok, just 1 problem... first time i load the page, i need to click 2 times over "User" to open fancybox...
If i open fancybox and then i close it, the second time i can click just 1 time...
why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first click registers the event to the DOM, and the second (and subsequent ones) show the Fancybox.

If using multiple Fancyboxes, you should avoid using ID's like you have there and change it to classes. Not sure why you've got all that code to launch the fancybox, when this should work:

```
$(".comment_button_fancy").fancybox();
```

This will Fancybox all elements with the class "comment_button_fancy" and should fix your two-clicks issue. You don't need to put a 'click' event handler around the Fancybox code, as it inherently has that event attached to it.